# What formula connects the moment of inertia and angular velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, momentum, angular-velocity, moment-of-inertia

I need to determine angular velocity of a disc when a man with given mass and speed whacks on the edge of it.

I calculated the total moment of inertia of disc and body, how do I calculate the angular velocity of the disc? ( radius and mass of the disc are also given ).

Comment: Is this homework? Please tag accordingly. And follow the rules for homework. Did you try Google? It is very handy. Ell equals eye omega sound familiar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L(angular momentum) = (moment of Inertia) x (angular velocity)

Comment: Try to use math formatting. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: -1 because although you answered the question, you did not provide additional information that might help the OP in the future. Like the fact that angular momentum above is _only_ valid on the center of mass. Otherwise you have to consider the parrallel axis theorem and the cross terms $ \vec{r} \times m \vec{v}$ from the motion of the center of mass.